# Item Price being Ignored in Cart Price Rules

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.2, discount, promotions

I'm trying to setup a promotion in Magento 2.2.2. and I'm really not getting the result that I want.
I want it to be like:
If you have at least 3 items in your Cart, and at least one (1) of the items is from the brand X Y or Z, apply 100% discount to an item in your cart that is from brand B - BUT to a maximum of €39.90

The goal here is to make people add products from X Y and Z, and I offer them a product from B.

I have set it up like this:

[image]
[image]

Now, the Conditions seem to work properly, what definitely does not work is the price range. 
If I add two products from brand B (the one that I am offering) the discount is being applied twice, even for products that are over 39.90.
If I add just one product from brand B that costs more than 39.90, the discount still gets applied in full.

Anyone has any idea or suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a sub category in the brand that I wanted, and putting all under 39.90 products into it. I then used that category for the Action instead of looking for the price.
Well, it might have been the obvious answer all along but took me a while to figure it out, though I just share !